# How to add a textfield in form and set email validation with out model class in YII?

Tags: php, validation, yii

Hello friend is it possible to create a custom field in form and set email validation.

```
<?php echo CHtml::textField('references', '', array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)) ?>
```

I want to allow user to insert only a valid email.

Comment: You mean you want to use model class validation without using model name in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution - to create a small model:

```
class EmailModel extends CFormModel {
    public $email;
    public function rules()
    {
        return array( array('email', 'email') );
    }
}
```

Only seven strings!

And in view:

```
$model = new EmailModel();
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'enableClientValidation'=>true
));
echo $form->error($model, 'email');
echo $form->emailField($model, 'email', array ( ));
$this->endWidget();
```

Comment: In model i define a public variable

public $references;

and add this code in my view 

<div class="row">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'references'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'references'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'references'); ?>
</div>

it work for me 
thanking you

Answer (score 0):

yes.. you can set jquery script in you view page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#references").blur(function(){
              //here set your email validation
         });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: couple things: `1.` it's called jQuery, not ajax.  `2.` the OP didn't mention anything about jQuery. they are not going to include the entire jQuery library just for form validation.

Comment: @sircapsalot yes its jQuery. jQuery library already included in yii.

Answer (score 0):

Two method mention below through user can enter only valid email

```
pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"
```

Second Method

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="text" name="email" value="">
```